# Datatype format exception for xsd:dateTime in SPARQL query with Jena?

Tags: java, xsd, rdf, sparql, jena

I am trying to apply a range query on a property of the RDF which is of `xsd:dateTime` format. This is my query:

```sql
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
SELECT ?x WHERE { ?y <DATE:> ?x . 
FILTER(?x>"2014-06-05T10:10:10+0530"^^xsd:dateTime) }
```

It gives warning and nothing as result:

```
WARN [main] (Log.java:78) - Datatype format exception: "2014-06-11T12:44:22+0530"^^xsd:dateTime
```

I don't understand what the problem is? I have stored the property in `xsd:dateTime` format only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have stored the property in xsd:dateTime format only.

The simple answer is that no, you have ***not*** stored the value as an xsd:dateTime. The standard  [xsd:dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) says:

> The lexical space of dateTime consists of finite-length sequences of
> characters of the form: `'-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss ('.' s+)? (zzzzzz)?`

Part of your dateTime matches that, viz., `2014-06-05T10:10:10`. However,

> `zzzzzz` (if present) represents the timezone (as described below).

When we look below, we see

> The lexical representation of a timezone is a string of the form:
> `(('+' | '-') hh ':' mm) | 'Z'`, where
>
> - `hh` is a two-digit numeral (with leading zeros as required) that represents the hours,
> - `mm` is a two-digit numeral that represents the minutes,
> - `'+'` indicates a nonnegative duration,
> - `'-'` indicates a nonpositive duration,
> - `'Z'` indicates a zero-timezone offset (UTC+0).

Your timezone doesn't match that.  I think you probably meant `+05:30`. and thus should have

```
"2014-06-05T10:10:10+05:30"^^xsd:dateTime
```

Sure enough, if we use Jena's command line tool `qparse`:

```
$ qparse --query query.rq # the original query, warnigns
14:12:22 WARN  NodeValue            :: Datatype format exception: "2014-06-05T10:10:10+0530"^^xsd:dateTime
14:12:22 WARN  NodeValue            :: Datatype format exception: "2014-06-05T10:10:10+0530"^^xsd:dateTime
14:12:22 WARN  NodeValue            :: Datatype format exception: "2014-06-05T10:10:10+0530"^^xsd:dateTime
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT  ?x
WHERE
  { ?y <DATE:> ?x
    FILTER ( ?x > "2014-06-05T10:10:10+0530"^^xsd:dateTime )
  }
```

```
$ qparse --query query.rq # the updated query, no warnings
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT  ?x
WHERE
  { ?y <DATE:> ?x
    FILTER ( ?x > "2014-06-05T10:10:10+05:30"^^xsd:dateTime )
  }
```

Comment: @user3654540 The moral of the story is:  if the system tells you you have a syntax error, check the syntax. :)